# Why create surrounding "neighborhoods" when using APL to iterate through the initial N by N game of life

Tags: apl

It seems that adding extra live and dead cells changes how the original "neighborhood" would progress through the generations.

When I apply the game of life rules to the initial N by N array, I get much different results going thru the generations than I get after surrounding the initial array with 8 reversed/transposed arrays.

Comment: Does [this](https://dfns.dyalog.com/n_life.htm) answer your question?

Comment: Great answer Adam. I'm happy you realized what my question was. I wish I had found that detailed website when googling for an answer. I found numerous sites videos that created the surrounding neighborhoods but none that explained why. I'm new to this forum so I don't know how to accept your answer - but I definitely do. Thank you.

Comment: @dawnbreaker I've written up [a more full-fledged answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75534738/5306507). Feel free to accept it using the ✔ checkmark to the left of the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whether a cell is alive or dead in the next generation, depends on the exact number of live cells in its [Moore neighbourhood](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore_neighborhood). What do you do with cells at the edges? If you just count the live cells in the existing neighbour positions, you effectively count the missing positions (outside the array) as being dead, which has a noticable effect. Alternatives include, but are not limited to, wrapping around to the opposite edge, and mirroring in the edge, but either way, you have a choice to make.

The [dfns workspace](http://apl.wiki/Dfns%20workspace) includes [notes on the Game of Life](https://dfns.dyalog.com/n_life.htm) which explains, illustrates, and implements many such options.